# Increment Cell Value by 1 using buttons (g.sheets)

Tags: button, google-sheets

I want to create some small buttons in my google sheet that add or substract the cell value incrementally.

*Excuse my artistic abilities (I created the buttons in paint)*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create the increment and decrement functions using Google Apps Script like this:

```
function increment1() {
  var activeCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell();
  var cellValue = activeCell.getValue();
  activeCell.setValue(++cellValue);
}

function decrement1() {
  var activeCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell();
  var cellValue = activeCell.getValue();
  activeCell.setValue(--cellValue);
}

function increment01() {
  var activeCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell();
  var cellValue = activeCell.getValue() + 0.1;
  activeCell.setValue(cellValue);
}

function decrement01() {
  var activeCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell();
  var cellValue = activeCell.getValue() - 0.1;
  activeCell.setValue(cellValue);
}
```

After saving the script, you can draw the buttons using `Insert menu -> Drawing`, then after you've finished the drawing and placed it onto the sheet, you can right click the drawing, then click on the three dots and select `Assign Script`:

[image]

Then type the function name on the dialog box that appears:

[image]

This would increment or decrement the value in the active/selected cell by 1 or 0.1, depending on the entered function.